# I have a worksheet with multiple tab and i want to separate each tab that contains same text into a separate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, macbook-pro

I have a worksheet with multiple tabs, can i get a VBA code that will separate each tab into multiple files

I want to make A1 and A1 SCREEN as one file, then B1 and B1 SCREEN be on another file and same goes for all the tabs containing same text.

TAB NAMES:
1.A1
2.A1 SCREEN
3.B1
4.B1 SCREEN
5.C1
6.C1 SCREEN

Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPg06.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SuperUser!
If it's quite simple, then something like this:

```
Sub extactTabs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cwb As Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
    Set cwb = ThisWorkbook
    For i = 1 To cwb.Worksheets.Count Step 2
        cwb.Worksheets(i).Copy
        Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        cwb.Worksheets(i + 1).Copy after:=nwb.Worksheets(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

The [**.Copy**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.copy) method without parameters will copy the specified sheet to a new workbook. This new book will become active, store it in a separate variable. Copy the next sheet into the memorized book after its only sheet.

Of course, the macro thinks that the sheets in your book are arranged like in your screenshot, one after the other. The macro does not check the names of the tabs, it just copies every two sheets into a separate workbook. You will only have to view the result and save the books to disk with the desired name.